# How to bring up the effect on core plot pie chart selected slice

Tags: core-plot

I am using core plot donut chart. I brought the chart, i need to bring the effect on the selected chart.How to bring this.

Comment: What effect do you want to add to the pie chart? "Explode" a slice? Change the color? Add a label?

Comment: I need to change the layout of the selected slice and need to change the colour of other slices, for one chart i know how to do it, but i am loading many charts in a tableview, i need to find which chart is selected, i tried out many methods to check,but i unable to get the selected chart row.

Answer (score 0):

Every plot delegate method passes the plot that sent the message as one of the parameters. Give each pie chart a unique `identifier` and use that to determine which one sent the message.